# OMNotebook Error: Class dev not found in scope (looking for a function or record)

Tags: openmodelica

I have modified the van der Pol example from DrModelica with the following changes:

```
model FPStirling "Free Piston Stirling engine model"
  Real x(start = 1,fixed = true);
  Real v(start = 1,fixed = true);
  Real T(start = 1,fixed = true);
  equation
  der(x) = v;
  dev(v) = T/x-1;
  dev(T) = 1 - x;
end FPStirling;
```

It evaluates and returns: `{FPStirling}`

Then I run: `simulate(FPStirling, startTime=0, stopTime=25 )`

But I get the output:

```
record SimulationResult
    resultFile = "",
    messages = "Failed to build model: FPStirling"
end SimulationResult;
OMC-ERROR: 
"[7:3-7:17] Error: Class dev not found in scope FPStirling (looking for a function or record).
Error: Error occurred while flattening model FPStirling
"
```

Could it be a path problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you really have a function `dev` defined somewhere? Or maybe its a typo for `der`.

Adeel.